# How do I scroll a WebView of an HTML string to a specific anchor?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I'm wondering how to scroll programmatically to a given anchor in a WebView.

The content I am showing is rendered by

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:someURL];
```

and thus I cannot simply navigate to #anchors by pointing them out in the URLs.

I'm looking for a method along the lines of

```
[[webView mainFrame] scrollToAnchor:@"anchor"]
```

but obviously it isn't there.

TIA

Comment: Are you saying you've tried including the ID in `baseURL`, but that didn't work?

Comment: No, I didn't think of the baseURL paying attention to that kind of information, doh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Javascript Bridge works, but you can also do the equivalent from Objective-C if you like:

```
DOMDocument *doc = [[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument];
DOMElement *element = [doc getElementById:@"anchor"];
[element scrollIntoView:YES];
```

Comment: This certainly is the clean way I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_STRING_WITHOUT_ANCHOR"]]];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {
   [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('YOUR_ANCHOR_HERE_WITHOUT_#').scrollIntoView(true);"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a workaround, but I don't know if this is the right way to do it. By getting the reference to the javascript context I can call javascript methods in the webFrame.

```
[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:@"document.getElementById('TheId').scrollIntoView(true);"];
```